# How could politicians protect themselves from hypnosis?

Tags: politics, security, mind-control, sleep, paranormal

In my world, [hypnotism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypnosis) is both powerful and reliable. With a few tools and a lot of suggestions, it is possible for trained hypnotists to put people in a trance-like state. While in this state, the victim will do almost anything the hypnotist's ask. Experiencing pain or being startled can knock a person out of a trance.

Obviously, politicians would be a high value target for hypnosis. This is because a hypnotized politician could either really embarrass themselves and end their career or they could be manipulated for domestic/foreign purposes. If powerful mentalists were around, how could politicians and other very important people make sure that they don't wind up being manipulated and saying/doing something that they shouldn't do?

Edit: How hypnosis works is that a hypnotist performs some repetitive action like swinging a pocket watch or stirring a glass while the subject watches. The hypnotist then keeps suggesting that the subject relaxes and stays calm. After about 3 minutes of this, if the subject is compliant, they get hypnotized. The tricky thing is that sly hypnotists can hypnotize people over the course of a casual conversation without the subject realizing it before it is too late. The sly hypnotist could just perform a minor repetitive action and get the subject to remain calm until they're in a trance.

Comment: .. how would a population protect itself from hypnosis by politicians ?

Comment: This is highly dependent on exactly how hypnosis works in your world. Without describing the rules of hypnosis we cannot talk about what countermeasures can be taken. Perhaps visualizing the sign of the cross is sufficient to protect yourself. Perhaps there are no countermeasures, perhaps you just need to avoid eye contact. Because of this lack of information this question is far too broad for this site.

Comment: In some fiction, hypnotizing someone happens near instantly. Like you would only need to be alone with them for a moment. In other fiction, it would require kidnapping the person and going to work on them in an empty room for a significant amount of time. So how does your hypnosis work in this regard? Because potential counter-measures are going to be influenced by this.

Comment: What if the hypnotists just hypnotized every person and politician to believe that hypnosis doesn't exist?............                                                   What if that's already happened to us?

Comment: "Experiencing pain or being startled can knock a person out of a trance."  As a tax paying citizen, I am in favor of a department of government charged with administering frequent, random, unscheduled, public, and powerful slaps to the face of elected officials.  Now... about this hypnotic trance thing... I'll have to think on that for a bit.

Comment: "reliable"? Then you've answered your own question with a no. How to not get gaffled up, strapped to a chair and Clockwork Oranged? That's called security. It'd be the same answer using sodium pentothal; the key is: don't get stuck with the needle.

Comment: What is the difference between this "hypnosis" and waving huge amounts of money in front of a politician today? It seems that the same result is happening.

Comment: How could you usefully distinguish 'politicians' from anyone else? Without that distinction, how could the idea, let alone the Question, matter?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## Life is pain

#### (anyone who says otherwise is selling something).

The answer is **pain**, which disturbs hypnosis.

In every world, technology develops in part to supplement or provide abilities we ourselves do not have. Our distant ancestors invented textiles to replace absent fur, and knives to replace claws. In the present, we supplant failing hips with titanium, support immune systems with antibiotics, and aid hearts with pacemakers and implantable cardioverter-defibrillators.

If we lived in a world where we did not have these problems, these technologies would not exist. We *do* live in a world where we are not vulnerable to hypnosis, so anti-hypnotic tech does not exist, but it could.

I propose an implanted monitor which tracks brain waves. When they match the induced hypnotic state, it shocks the bearer enough to either wake them from the hypnotic state, or prevent them from falling into it. Naturally, every serious politician would have one, but they’d likely be almost universal, just like vaccinations. What sane parent would send a child out of their sight without one?

Comment: Slapping the politician is cheaper and will probably win in the public polls.

Comment: @hszmv less so for five year olds

Comment: Of course.  Because one is a group of poorly educated immature brats that have no grasp of basic human decency, empathy, or tolarance for the wants and needs of others.   The other is a group of Kindergarteners.

Answer (score 19):

/In my world, hypnotism is both powerful and reliable/

**Pre-emptive strike**

Your politicians are all hypnotized by powerful and reliable hypnotists to ignore hypnotic suggestion.  In your world this worked better than expected - politicans not only paid no attention to hypnotists but also ignored in person suggestions, information and complaints by lobbyists and constituents. Information and new knowledge obtained by hypnotically protected politicians was all through reading.  Information was thus much less biased by the communication skills (hypnotic or no) of persons advocating one or another policy choice.

The inability of hypnotically protected politicians to listen to other people did cause them some trouble at home.

Comment: "*In your world this worked better than expected - politicians not only paid no attention to hypnotists but also ignored in-person suggestions, ... complaints by lobbyists and constituents*, as well as any other information. Politicians never changed their mind on any issue."

Comment: What's the difference between "information [from] lobbyists and constituents" and "information [from] reading"? Why would one work and not the other? If a constituent were to write something (like a lie presented as a fact) down, would that get around this problem?

Comment: @NotThatGuy - it would.  And the politician would consider what was written without being distracted by the fact that the person who had written it was super hot, or had done him favors, or was loud and annoying, or was a hypnotist.  All info in writing levels the playing field, in addition to protecting from hypnosis.

Comment: It may "level the playing field" somewhat, but writing can still heavily influence decisions in irrational ways, and it can be as full of appeals to emotion or lies as spoken language (you don't have to go any further than your least favourite news website for a demonstration of this, regardless of your political orientation). It doesn't seem like this accomplishes too much.

Comment: @NotThatGuy.  OK.  Information is conveyed only in the form of haiku and interpretive dance.

Answer (score 12):

**Be Old as B*lls**

[image]

Politicians are mostly old crotchety men. Against all odds this turns out to be a good thing.

You see young people are vulnerable to hypnotic suggestion because they have a storm of new thoughts popping off morning noon at night. It is hard to distinguish what thought they came up with the one that was hypnotically implanted in your brain.

Old people are different because they are essentially robots. And you cannot hypnotise a robot. Everyone knows it just cannot be done.

These withered old dinosaurs are ossified and operate on auto-pilot. They seize up if they have to do anything fundamentally new or answer a question they were unprepared for. Fortunately they have been around the block so many times they have their reactions prepared for anything that might happen. Only they will react the same way as they did 20 years ago. Usually by talking about the budget for fifteen minutes while being careful not to say anything specific.

That means if a rogue thought pops up it will be noticed immediately as the first thought they had that day. Then the training kicks in and they report to their handlers for reprogramming.

Even if the implanted thought does sneak through, the victim will likely not have the secondary skills to carry it out. If Senator Oldbones is implanted with the message to assassinate Speaker Fartface at todays congress, then he is stuck because he doesn't know where to find a weapon. He knows where the knives are kept at home. They are in the knife drawer. Unless they are dirty. The dirty ones get put away and then magically reappear the next day. But he is not at home today. He is in the Senate house.

This leads to him either driving home in the middle of the day, when he should be on the floor, or wandering the halls mumbling to the custodial staff about how he needs to butter some bread. Both strange behaviors are picked up on and the senator is sent back for reprogramming. Hooray!

Comment: I regret I have but one Like to give. This is brilliant and made me laugh out loud.

Comment: Its worth adding that being old is not just some theoretical handwavy protection.  Young people actually are in the real world more acceptable to hypnosis.

Comment: Why is Robert Picardo in that image?  He's not a politician.  Nor is he all that old in that picture compared to the rest of them...

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Robicardo is an Easter Egg I snuck in after the question was posted. Good job spotting him!

Comment: @Nosajimiki Another problem with young people is they think they invented sex!

Comment: @DarrelHoffman as the holographic Doctor on Voyager, he was literally an unhypnotizable machine, much to the point of the answer.

Answer (score 7):

**Politicians are very good at passing laws that protect politicians...**

If you think about it, what protects politicians from angry gun owners? Yes, there are those few gutsy crazies like [John Hinckley Jr.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Hinckley_Jr.) who will take the risk and try to step past the defenders, but for the most part, the traditional protection works remarkably well.

*Law.*

Whether we're talking about your local department of transportation hiding whether or not they're going to bypass your town with a new freeway or your local potentate's critical national secrets, the reality is that a hypnotist can do a lot of damage if a lot of damage weren't being risked in return.

So it's reasonable to assume that politicians would pass laws making hypnotism of any public official a [capital offense](https://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/capital_offense) little different from any other act of treason and punishable by death.

Save in the cases of the crazies and the *incredibly confident...* problem solved.

**Notes:**

1. You don't explain how hypnotism works in your world, so there's no way to explain what the politicians can do to physically defend themselves. We can always throw out vague things like, "they train mentally to resist hypnotism," but that doesn't say much and doesn't add much to the rules of your world.
2. Insofar as I understand hypnotism, it isn't like radio. The hypnotist must be present and within visual and audible contact of the target. Thus, bodyguards will also add to the politicians' protection.
3. If hypnotism is as powerful as you suggest, most communities would be investigating how to employ hypnotism as part of their judicial process. Nations would be employing it for espionage and spying. In the process, a great deal would be learned about how to defend against the very weapons those municipalities and nations are employing.

**And finally...**

If hypnotism were that powerful, average citizens would be losing their life savings to unscrupulous hypnotists. The legal system would very quickly begin licensing hypnotists, regulating their activities, and an entire suite of laws would quickly come to pass making hypnotists horrendously liable for what they do. If this doesn't sound a bit like the laws governing gun ownership, you might not be paying attention.  As the Good Book says, where much is given, much is required.

Answer (score 4):

### Guards

It's always useful to have someone watching your back. You might not be aware of being hypnotised, but people around you will probably notice.

Many politicians are protected by personal bodyguards, secret-service, mercenaries or just plain policemen.

These individuals may be trained to watch for the signs of someone being hypnotised, or the kind of language and behaviour that leads to it.
The role of bodyguard may therefore not end at the physical security, it may include the security of their charge's mind too.

### Fortification and counter-hypnosis.

Hypnotism is most effective against the unwary and unprepared.

A vital public official (or worried joe-punter) might engage the services of a trainer to teach them to defend their minds against this.

This would start with Mindfulness and Awareness of what's happening, and at the extreme upper-end, incorporate small hypnotically implanted micro-suggestions which act to shock the person out of whatever trances they may be entering.

The politician might start slowly slipping into the trance, and then abruptly snap out of it with whatever warning-signals they have implanted in their subconscious ringing hard.
They'd then know the person in front of them is attempting to hypnotise them, and can act accordingly.

**Narrative Improvements**
For purposes of narrative interest and the need for things to not be perfect, this hypnotic defence-layer might interfere with the ability to actually sleep, every time you start drifting off to sleep, you'd snap to wakefulness with mental alarm bells ringing due to the false-positives.

To deal with this, a person with this system in place might need to go through a series of nightly rituals.
Sitting in front of a mirror and repeating a code-phrase three times, or wearing their Sleep-Amulet.
Basically disarming their defences for the night.

This may make them vulnerable if they're accosted in the night by a hypnotist, or fail to reactivate their defences in the morning for some reason.

Answer (score 4):

Several possibilities (likely all of them will be used):

1. Legal. The same way politicians are protected from assassins - by making murder a serious crime with grave enough punishment to deter almost everyone from killing your politician, no matter how you hate him/her/them, and making police investigation throw *a lot* of effort into murder cases.
2. Sunglasses. 'nough said. (Now I wonder why sunglasses are so popular in the USA and why USA is the dominant country on Earth)
3. Optical distraction. Assuming plain sunglasses do not work, wear glasses with minuscule mirror specks embedded in them - as you make tiny head movements, they generate flashes that distract you enough from falling into the trance.
4. Concentration distraction. Wear [uncomfortable dress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suit), not uncomfortable enough that you cannot do your work, but enough that you cannot relax. This might extend into corporations, top level management just *cannot afford* wear anything else, and the more important they feel, the more likely they are to [order their employees to wear](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dress_code) such dresses as well. Politicians that wear [more comfortable](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D0%B8_%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D1%87%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE_%D1%83_%D0%84%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83_%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%8E%D0%B7%D1%96,_1.jpg#/media/File:%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D0%B8_%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D1%87%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE_%D1%83_%D0%84%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83_%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%8E%D0%B7%D1%96,_1.jpg), [less oppressing dress](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Muammar_al-Gaddafi-2-30112006.jpg) might be often pulling short straws.

Answer (score 1):

Shift social expectations and political norms.

In the real world, many women are [scared](https://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2021/apr/06/women-are-scared-to-enter-politics-because-of-their-past-i-was-one-of-them) to enter politics because they fear that some grumpy ex will send their nudes to the tabloids. There are legal ways to counteract this fear, such as making the tabloid legally culpable for prosecution, but the photo could still be submitted to anonymous Internet sites where such laws are hard to enforce. What really needs to happen is to shift social norms. The default response should be to blame the leaker and consider the woman a victim.

If hypnotism is a real risk in your world, a similar pr effort will be needed so that instead of "pervy president took his kit off at the State of Union" the general discussion is muted tones of "poor man!" with perhaps a good hearted "honestly, I hope I look as good at his age!"

That's key for the pr side. The more important (to the country) practical question is how to avoid a hypnotised President doing something terrible- declaring war on France perhaps. For this, the answer is the same as without hypnotism. Structure the government such that no individual or sufficiently small group to get compromised is able to take such consequential action unilaterally.

This won't solve everything, but it should help any other suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

**Monitoring**

They will undergo some hypnosis sessions and the characteristic patterns of blood pressure and pulsations will be measured. Then they will carry a bracelet and another sensor to constantly monitor the state. If an hypnotic status is detected a small electric shock will wake up the politician.